# Diferença entre position absolute e position relative

Tags: css

De forma resumida qual é a diferença entre **`position: absolute`** e **`position: relative`** em CSS?

Comment: Muito obrigado @jbueno ,reforçou o entendimento

Comment: Eu? Mas por quê?

Answer (score -4):

o `absolute` todo o conteudo tende a respeitar a posição dele.
já o `relative` respeita a posição do conteudo.

Comment: Me esclareceu, muito obrigado @Léo Andrade